# Set Cache Limit or Expiration for S3FS

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

I have this option "-o use_cache=/tmp" set when I mount my S3 bucket.  Is there a limit on how much room it will try to use in tmp?  Is there a way to limit that or otherwise expire items after X amount of time?

Comment: That would be a great add-on.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the (unsupported) [`sample_delcache.sh` script from the s3fs-fuse project](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/blob/master/test/sample_delcache.sh). Set up a cron job to run it every so often. There'd still be the risk of running out space (or inodes, as I just did) before the next time you ran the cleanup script, but you should be able to dial it in.

Answer (score 2):

At this time there is an option **ensure_diskfree** to preserve some space.

Answer (score 1):

The local cache's growth is apparently unbounded but it is truly a "cache" (as opposed to what might be called a "working directory") in the sense that it can be safely purged at any time, such as with a cron job that removes files after a certain age, combining `find` and `xargs` and `rm`.

(`xargs` isn't strictly necessary, but it avoids issues that can occur when too many files are found to remove in one invocation.)